# Kendo UI Chart value axis step values are not displayed in the chart

Tags: kendo-ui, bar-chart

I am trying to display a bar chart using Kendo UI. The series labels are getting displayed.But the value axis is not marked with step values.For eg:if my series data is like {3,6,8} and the step size is 2 the series axis is not marked with {2,4,6,8,10} etc.The chart is displayed and labels are displayed as 3,6 & 8.The category axis values are also getting displayed.

[image: click to see how the chart is rendered now.]

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: Are your category axis labels set to visible: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#configuration-categoryAxis.labels.visible